# Is it possible to stream an audio signal over an SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, audio, putty

This is a pretty loaded question - I'm pretty sure I know the answer, but I'm still a novice so I figured I'd ask.

I run a mud client(http://tintin.sourceforge.net/) on a Ubuntu 10 Server system. I then SSH into said system to play via the mud client. The mud client offers audio alerts, and I'd like to set these up. I'm assuming if I were locally playing on the system I could set up some kind of audio output even in console and hear it via speakers. My question is - is there any way to set the audio alerts to send audio through SSH? The audio I'd be playing is just simple wav files.

Again, fairly certain I know the answer is no, but just wanted to check with persons smarter than I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the answer is yes. Create a remote tunnel over SSH, [use `socat` to connect the local end to your PulseAudio daemon](http://razor.occams.info/blog/2009/02/11/pulseaudio-sound-forwarding-across-a-network/), set `$PULSE_SERVER` on the remote end to its end of the tunnel, and use `paplay` to play the files.

Comment: Would that work when the remote system is a Windows system? I'd be using putty/putty tray.

Comment: There is actually a PulseAudio daemon available for Windows so it theoretically should work, with a bit of tinkering.